# How to simultaneously use sapply and apply to shorten a multiplicative function in R

Tags: r, function, lapply, sapply

I was wondering how I could use `sapply` and `lapply` simultaneously so that I could avoid writing my function called `GG` as it appears below?

```
GG = function(x, y) dnorm(250, mean = x, sd = y)*dnorm(265, mean = x, sd = y) *
                    dnorm(259, mean = x, sd = y)
```

**P.S.** I know if only `x` in my function above was varying, the following could work:

```
     function(x) sapply(lapply(x, dnorm, x = c(250, 265, 259), 10), prod)
```

But in my case `x` and `y` both vary.

Comment: You should have provided the full context.  I was only trying to replicate your GG function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` with `Reduce` from  `base R`.  The reason for using `Map` is that functions can be applied on corresponding elements of the objects passed into it.  Here, `dnorm` is the function which takes each corresponding element of 'x' and 'y' as the `mean` and `sd`  arguments while it has a constant vector of "x" (`c(250, 265, 259)`).  The output of `Map` is a `list` and we `Reduce` the corresponding elements of `list` to a single one by multiplying (`*`)

```
GG1 <- function(x, y) Reduce(`*`, Map(dnorm, x = c(250, 265, 259),
                        mean = list(x), sd = list(y)))
identical(GG(24, 12), GG1(24, 12))
#[1] TRUE

identical(GG(32, 15), GG1(32, 15))
#[1] TRUE
```

Based on the OP's comments,

```
x <- seq(10,  40, length= 30)
y <- x
z <- outer(x, y, GG1)
persp(x, y, z , theta = 0, phi = 20, expand = 0.5, col = 'pink')
```

[image]

Comment: @parvinkarimi  INstead of `outer`, try with `expand.grid` i.e. `z <- matrix(apply(expand.grid(x, y), 1, FUN = function(u) GG1(u[1], u[2])), 30, 30)`

Comment: @parvinkarimi  That you will also get with your function (if you have tried it).  Here, the 'z' values are all 0s (please check the 'z' output base don your function as well. `z <- outer(x, y, FUN = GG);
all(z==0)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @parvinkarimi  I modified the earlier function and it now works with `outer`, but your `z` values based on 'x' and 'y' are all 0's which you have to check